# Get number of integers per file line

Tags: c, file-io, c-strings

I have a file with # signs and integers. I would like to avoid reading in the # signs and calculate the number of integers per line. I am new to C and would appreciate any tips and help!

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_NUM 1000
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 2048


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN], *p;
    int i, array[MAX_NUM] = { 0 }, count = 0;


    char filename[100];
    printf("Enter the file name: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);


    fp = fopen(filename,"r");


while (((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) && (count < MAX_NUM)) {
    if (strlen(line) > 1) {
        //counter for line number.
        count++;
        //this line does not contains numbers.
        if (line[0] == '#')continue;
        do {
            //notice. this way we count 111 as one number instead of 3.
            if (isdigit((int)*p) && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\0')) {
array[count] ++;
            }
        } while (*p++ != '\0');
    }
//printf("array[]: %d", array[i]);


int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; ++ i){
 printf("%d",array[i]);
}

}


    return(0);

}
```

Comment: what you mean by `calculate the value`. what should be a preferred result ?

Comment: If `#` means a commented line, you'll have to test for it, because of this line `# these have 5 integers` which itself contains an integer. For all other lines, use `strtok`.

Comment: Can you please post the output you are expecting?

Comment: How can both `isdigit((int)*p)` be true and also `*p` is space or `NUL`?

Comment: @Barmar that's not OP's original code. He copied it from an answer.

Comment: Please leave your original code in the question. How is someone reading this in the future supposed to know what the original problem was and how an answer solved it? SO is supposed to be a long-term repository of problems and solutions, you mustn't remove the problem from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version of what I think you are trying to do - count the integers and not the individual digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_NUM 1000
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 2048

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[100];
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char *p;
    int i;
    int array[MAX_NUM] = { 0 };
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter the file name: \n");
    if (scanf("%s", filename) != 1)
        fatal("Bad filename entry");
    if ((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)
        fatal("Unable to open the file");

    while ((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) {
        if (count >= MAX_NUM)
            fatal("Broke the array");
        if (line[0] != '#') {
            p = strtok(line, " ");
            while (p != NULL) {
                if(isdigit(*p))
                    array[count]++;
                p = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(array[i]) {
            printf("Integers: %d\n", array[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Enter the file name:
test.txt
Integers: 9
Integers: 4
Integers: 5
Integers: 5
Integers: 5
Integers: 1
Integers: 20
```

Comment: I already asked you to show an example of the output you are expecting. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Wonderful wonderful! Thank you so much for all your help throughout this process. I appreciate it.

Comment: I have an after question. How does strtok work? and please explain the use of "fatal". Thanks.

Comment: `fatal` is just an easy way to keep the main code down - it could have been inline code. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx) will tell you about `strtok`, which breaks a text line into tokens. There might be better references too if you do a search. Also `strsep` might prove useful. `strtok` can be awkward - there are some pitfalls, such as trying to use it on a string literal, or trying to work with 2 strings at the same time.

Comment: So for clarification, strtok here:  p = strtok(NULL, " "); says the contents of line is null and the delimiter is an empty string so set p to that null value? And fatal is a form of error checking that is kept tucked away from the main code for cleanliness?

Comment: Please read the man page - this is no tutorial. The second and other times you call `strtok` (for a particular string) you pass the `NULL` pointer instead of the actual string pointer.

Comment: I understand. Thank you, again!

Comment: `fatal` is not error checking. it just reports what it is told to report and exits the program.

Comment: Like a more elegant way of exiting the program when an error arises?

Comment: There are probably better ways, but that's what I did. I keeps the main code clutter free. But you *do have to* check the return values from these functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are doing. You are reading the file, skipping each *blank* or *comment* line and then counting the number of integers you find in each line saving the integer count (per-line) in `array[]`. You were on the right track, you just had a few hiccups.

While you can approach the problem using the various `string.h` and `ctype.h` tools, it is sometimes better to simply use a pointer and work your way down each line a character at a time. You have already created the pointer `p`, which you can use to find the number of occurrences of the integers in each line.

The easy way to approach it is to check the first char in `line` (therefore `*p`). If it is equal to a `newline` or `'#'`, the line is empty or a *comment* -- skip the line. Next, for each character in the line, you want to advance `p` until a digit is found. You can use `isdigit`, or simply use:

```
    while (*p && (*p < '0' || '9' < *p)) p++;
```

After you have found a digit, increment the integer count:

```
    if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') array[count]++;
```

(**note:** it is `array[count]++;` NOT `array[count++];`)

Then simply advance over all the digits in that integer and when you reach the next non-digit character, repeat the loop:

```
    while (*p && ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')) p++;
```

When you reach the end of the line, increment `count` (which is serving as your *line-counter*, not your integer count) and go to the next line.

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following. Note: the program expects the *filename* to be given as the first argument, or if no argument is given, it will read from `stdin` by default:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAX_NUM = 1000, MAX_LINE_LEN = 2048 };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN], *p;
    int i, array[MAX_NUM] = { 0 }, count = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate the file is open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    while (count < MAX_NUM && (p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp))) {
        if (*p == '\n' || *p == '#') { count++; continue; }
        while (*p) { /* for each char in line */
            while (*p && (*p < '0' || '9' < *p)) p++;
            if ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9') array[count]++;
            while (*p && ('0' <= *p && *p <= '9')) p++;
        }
        count++;  /* increment line count */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose(fp);

    printf ("\nThe lines from '%s' contained the following integers:\n\n",
            argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("  line[%3d] : %d\n", i, array[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return(0);
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
$ cat ../dat/commentint.txt
# each burst is one long
1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 5
14 62 48 14

# these have 5 integers
1 3 5 7 9
123 456 789 1234 5678
34 34 34 34 34

# special case, I guess
1

# now a burstful sequence
1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 1 1
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/skipcomment ../dat/commentint.txt

The lines from '../dat/commentint.txt' contained the following integers:

  line[  0] : 0
  line[  1] : 9
  line[  2] : 4
  line[  3] : 0
  line[  4] : 0
  line[  5] : 5
  line[  6] : 5
  line[  7] : 5
  line[  8] : 0
  line[  9] : 0
  line[ 10] : 1
  line[ 11] : 0
  line[ 12] : 0
  line[ 13] : 20
```

Let me know if you have questions.

---

**Only Printing Lines With Integers Found**

To only show the lines with integers, just add an `if` statement to your print loop. e.g.:

```
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (array[i])
            printf ("  line[%3d] : %d\n", i, array[i]);
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/skipcomment ../dat/commentint.txt

The lines from '../dat/commentint.txt' contained the following integers:

  line[  1] : 9
  line[  2] : 4
  line[  5] : 5
  line[  6] : 5
  line[  7] : 5
  line[ 10] : 1
  line[ 13] : 20
```

Comment: That's simple enough -- do you want to only show the lines with integers and how many?

Comment: OK, I updated to code to show you how. All that is needed is an `if` statement. The code already skipped all blank or comment lines, it just printed the results of each line. All that was needed was to only print line numbers that contained integers. If you only want to `count` lines with integers, just remove `count++;` from the first line in the loop. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
    if (isdigit((int)*p) && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\0')) {
        array[count] ++;
    }
```

It's not possible for both conditions of the `&&` to be true. If the character is a space or null byte, then it can't also be a digit. Try this:

```
while (((p = fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp)) != NULL) && (count <= MAX_NUM)) {
    if (line[0] != '\0' && line[0] != '\n') { // Skip empty lines
        //counter for line number.
        count++;
        //this line does not contains numbers.
        if (line[0] == '#')continue;
        int in_number = 0;
        do {
            if (isdigit((int) *p)) {
                in_number = 1;
            } else if (in_number && (*p == ' ' || *p == '\n' || *p == '\0')) {
                // only count the space or end-of-string immediately after a number
                array[count] ++;
                in_number = 0;
            }
        } while (*p++ != '\0');
    }
}
```